choosing penalty for GAM in mgcv, difference between bs = "ts" or select = TRUE?
I am working on some environmental data, using GAM models for understanding what governs DOC in soils. And I am having some issues with choosing an adequate GAM model and penalties. In mgcv::gam there are two ways of introducing additional penalties to the covariates:
*) bs = "ts for thin plate splines; bs = "cs" for cubic splines, for penalizing the null space.
*) select = TRUE for a double penalty on all the splines in the model, which penalizes both null and range space.
More infos here and here.
I have these four models
mod1 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2) + s(x3), select = TRUE)
mod2 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1, bs = "ts") + s(x2, bs = "cs) + s(x3, bs = "ts"))
mod3 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1) + s(x2, bs = "cr") + s(x3), select = TRUE)
mod4 <- mgcv::gam(y ~ s(x1, bs = "ts") + s(x2, bs = "cs") + s(x3, bs = "ts"), select = TRUE)
s(x1) and s(x3) being predictors of some significance and s(x2) being time.
what I try doing here: I want to choose the a model via additional penalties while also choosing the type of spline basis function for some of the variables, and I am confused about the usage of the shrinkage approach vs. the double penalty approach.
To me the model mod4 doesn´t make sense since it will inflict the double penalty of select = TRUE on the range and null space of the basis splines while the null space of the splines is already penalized by the "ts" and "cs" shrinkage versions.
At the same time mod3 looks to me the best choice in cases where you have a time variable you with to smooth via bs = "cr" plus a covariate and you wish to penalize both smooth terms in both null and range space for model selection.
From my basic understanding of this, the best choice would be mod2 or mod3 since mod1 would just assume thin plates basis functions for all the smooths, and that is not the case since s(x2) is time.
Lastly, in case mod4 specification in completely wrong, shouldn´t mgcv::gam pop up a warning or an error?

Did you mean to write s(x3, bs = "ts") in mod4?

Yes, I did actually. Thanks for spotting it.
